# Website for timezone conversion

Tags: webapp-rec, time-zone

I am looking for a website that allows me to convert time between different timezones in an ubiquitous way.

Most websites have input restraints that only allow me to type in a specific city or to select a time zone from a pre-determined list. I am searching for something that has a set of features similar to these:

- Automatically detects my current location
- I can type in a city and a timezone and it will show the time difference
- Accepts a broad range of timezone formats (EST, UTC, GMT, etc.)

These are just general guidelines. The basic idea is that I want to know when will something happen without knowing much about timezone abbreviations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [compare](http://time.is/compare) feature from [time.is](http://time.is/)

For example,

Comparing New York and GMT at 9:00 gives the following

> When the time was 09:00 on Tuesday, August 16 in New York, it was
>   13:00 in GMT.
>   Time since then: 7 hours, 18 minutes and 24 seconds
>   New York is 4 hours behind GMT.

```
New York    GMT (+4h)
Tue 09:00   Tue 13:00
Tue 10:00   Tue 14:00
Tue 11:00   Tue 15:00
Tue 12:00   Tue 16:00
Tue 13:00   Tue 17:00
Tue 14:00   Tue 18:00
Tue 15:00   Tue 19:00
Tue 16:00   Tue 20:00
Tue 17:00   Tue 21:00
Tue 18:00   Tue 22:00
Tue 19:00   Tue 23:00
Tue 20:00   Wed 00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Google will tell you the current time in cities that it recognizes:

at 8:25pm in New York, searching [Time in Budapest] results in

```
 2:25am Wednesday (CEST) - Time in Budapest, Hungary
```

If you use iGoogle, there is a module you can add to your page [here](http://www.google.com/ig/adde?moduleurl=www.binaryturf.com/files/others/timeconvertor/replysntz.xml) that lets you select any "from" and "to" timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I like and use this [one](http://timeanddate.com/time/map/). It usually works well for me, so long as I google which time zone the place is in, if it's not one of the mapped cities.

Answer (score 0):

I find [worldtime buddy](http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/) to be one of the most useful!